# How to reformat CSV to be in UTF-8

Tags: python, csv, pandas, encoding, utf-8

Here is my code:

```
import tabula
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
import smtplib
from datetime import datetime
import time

root = Tk()
root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("PDF Files","*.pdf"),("All files","*.*")))

tabula.convert_into(root.fileName, "_ExportedPDF.csv", output_format="csv", pages="all")

path = root.fileName

with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as infile, open(path + 'final.csv', 'w') as outfile:
     inputs = csv.reader(infile)
     output = csv.writer(outfile)

     for index, row in enumerate(inputs):
         # Create file with no header
         if index == 0:
             continue
         output.writerow(row)

df = pd.read_csv('_ExportedPDF.csv')
# print (df)
root.destroy()
```

So, before I added the whole conversion to utf-8 clause, I was getting this error saying that it could not decode. So I added the utf-8 conversion and I am now getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BregmanM/Documents/Python/PDF to Excel/RiskSummary/risk-summary.py", line 29, in <module>
    output.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Users\BregmanM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0512' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
```

Is there a simple fix to make everything turn into utf-8? The CSV I have outputted is totally perfect, so I am confused as to why I can't get it to be read in a dataframe.

Comment: Where is the error being thrown? Please provide the full stack trace. Both of them, for both errors.

Comment: This might sound dumb, but what exactly is that? Do you mean the Traceback this above the actual error?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: Did you try using `open(path + 'final.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile` ?

Comment: Now, I'm getting the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BregmanM/Documents/Python/PDF to Excel/RiskSummary/risk-summary.py", line 25, in <module>
    for index, row in enumerate(inputs):
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Just a simple logic error. I was having the path open a PDF instead of the CSV. Thanks for your help!